# K8S ingress-nginx Client request body buffering to a temporary file

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-nginx

Been running into a strange warning with ingress-nginx on a K8S deployment.
Basically, the error is
`2023/02/16 15:56:03 [warn] 34#34: *7840048 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /tmp/nginx/client-body/0000009342, client: <client ip>, server: <hostname>, request: "POST /next HTTP/2.0", host: "<hostname>", referrer: "<hostname>"`

The deployment was made with helm, using default values; the helm chart version is ingress-nginx-4.3.0 and app version is 1.4.0
What's even more annoying is that I get this warning for requests having the body as small as 500 bytes.

The gist of it all is, I'm not sure if this warning causes the following scenario: the upstream gets the request, but **the client gets no reply (not even a 4xx/5xx Error)**. Been going over logs like crazy, but there's nothing conclusive to figure out if I can safely ignore this warning.

Thanks!

Deployed Helm chart in a different K8S cluster, using all default values with same result.
Increased the timeout on the upstream side to 60s.

Comment: I hope the shared information was helpful to you in overcoming the issue. If you have any further queries, I am happy to offer further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This warning message means that the size of the uploaded file was larger than the in-memory buffer reserved for uploads.

Refer to [document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_buffer_size) explaining how `client_body_buffer_size` works:

> Sets buffer size for reading client request body. In case the request
> body is larger than the buffer, the whole body or only its part is
> written to a temporary file. By default, buffer size is equal to two
> memory pages. This is 8K on x86, other 32-bit platforms, and x86-64.
> It is usually 16K on other 64-bit platforms.

So, lower the value of the uploaded file according to client_body_buffer_size to remove that warning  .This buffer is only used while a request body is being uploaded. Once the upload is complete the memory is free to be used for another request.